# fs.createWriteStream does not immediately create file?

Tags: node.js

I have made a simple *download from http* function as below (error handling is omitted for simplifcation):

```js
function download(url, tempFilepath, filepath, callback) {
    var tempFile = fs.createWriteStream(tempFilepath);
    http.request(url, function(res) {
        res.on('data', function(chunk) {
            tempFile.write(chunk);
        }).on('end', function() {
            tempFile.end();
            fs.renameSync(tempFile.path, filepath);
            return callback(filepath);
        })
    });
}
```

However, as I call `download()` tens of times asynchronously, it seldom reports error on `fs.renameSync` complaining it cannot find file at `tempFile.path`.

```
Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory 'xxx'
```

I used the same list of urls to test it, and it failed about 30% of time. The same list of urls worked when downloaded one by one.

Testing some more, I found out that the following code

```js
fs.createWriteStream('anypath');
console.log(fs.exist('anypath'));
console.log(fs.exist('anypath'));
console.log(fs.exist('anypath'));
```

does not always print `true`, but sometimes the first answer prints `false`.

I am suspecting that too many asynchronous `fs.createWriteStream` calls cannot guarantee the file creation. Is this true? Are there any methods to guarantee file creation?

Answer (score 77, accepted):

You shouldn't call `write` on your `tempFile` write stream until you've received the `'open'` event from the stream.  The file won't exist until you see that event.

For your function:

```
function download(url, tempFilepath, filepath, callback) {
    var tempFile = fs.createWriteStream(tempFilepath);
    tempFile.on('open', function(fd) {
        http.request(url, function(res) {
            res.on('data', function(chunk) {
                tempFile.write(chunk);
            }).on('end', function() {
                tempFile.end();
                fs.renameSync(tempFile.path, filepath);
                return callback(filepath);
            });
        });
    });
}
```

For your test:

```
var ws = fs.createWriteStream('anypath');
ws.on('open', function(fd) {
    console.log(fs.existsSync('anypath'));
    console.log(fs.existsSync('anypath'));
    console.log(fs.existsSync('anypath'));
});
```

Comment: Somehow, this snippet of code didn't download some of the last bytes. Instead, I listen to `finish` on `tempFile` now and `res.pipe(tempFile)` instead of doing it manually.

Comment: The [fs.js source](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/lib/fs.js#L1690) indicates that there is no need to wait for the `'open'` event before calling `write` on the write stream, as that is handled internally.

Comment: `open` is indeed handled internally, but it's async, the file is not open until the `open` event is emitted.

Answer (score 19):

The accepted answer didn't download some of the last bytes for me.
Here's a [Q](https://github.com/kriskowal/q) version that works correctly (but without the temp file).

```
'use strict';

var fs = require('fs'),
    http = require('http'),
    path = require('path'),
    Q = require('q');

function download(url, filepath) {
  var fileStream = fs.createWriteStream(filepath),
      deferred = Q.defer();

  fileStream.on('open', function () {
    http.get(url, function (res) {
      res.on('error', function (err) {
        deferred.reject(err);
      });

      res.pipe(fileStream);
    });
  }).on('error', function (err) {
    deferred.reject(err);
  }).on('finish', function () {
    deferred.resolve(filepath);
  });

  return deferred.promise;
}

module.exports = {
  'download': download
};
```

Note I'm listening to `finish` on file stream instead of `end` on response.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I use to get it done:

```
function download(url, dest) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        http.get(url, (res) => {
            if (res.statusCode !== 200) {
                var err = new Error('File couldn\'t be retrieved');
                err.status = res.statusCode;
                return reject(err);
            }
            var chunks = [];
            res.setEncoding('binary');
            res.on('data', (chunk) => {
                chunks += chunk;
            }).on('end', () => {
                var stream = fs.createWriteStream(dest);
                stream.write(chunks, 'binary');
                stream.on('finish', () => {
                    resolve('File Saved !');
                });
                res.pipe(stream);
            })
        }).on('error', (e) => {
            console.log("Error: " + e);
            reject(e.message);
        });
    })
};
```

Comment: Note: Manage huge data, it's better to pipe the response chunk with file write stream.

Answer (score 0):

I am working on uploading and downloading file (docx, pdf, text, etc) through nodejs `request-promise` and `request` libraries.

Problem with `request-promise` is that they don't promisify `pipe` method from `request` package. Hence, we need to do it in the old way.

I was able to come up with the hybrid solution, where I was able to use `async/await` and `Promise()` at same time. Here is the example:

```
    /**
     * Downloads the file.
     * @param {string} fileId : File id to be downloaded.
     * @param {string} downloadFileName : File name to be downloaded.
     * @param {string} downloadLocation : File location where it will be downloaded.
     * @param {number} version : [Optional] version of the file to be downloaded.
     * @returns {string}: Downloaded file's absolute path.
     */
    const getFile = async (fileId, downloadFileName, downloadLocation, version = undefined) => {
        try {
            const url = version ? `http://localhost:3000/files/${fileId}?version=${version}` : 
`${config.dms.url}/files/${fileUuid}`;
            const fileOutputPath = path.join(downloadLocation, fileName);

            const options = {
                method: 'GET',
                url: url,
                headers: {
                    'content-type': 'application/json',
                },
                resolveWithFullResponse: true
            }

            // Download the file and return the full downloaded file path.
            const downloadedFilePath = writeTheFileIntoDirectory(options, fileOutputPath);

            return downloadedFilePath;
        } catch (error) {
           console.log(error);
        }
    };
```

As you can see in above `getFile` method, we are using latest ES supported `async/await` functionality for asynchronous programming. Now, lets look into `writeTheFileIntoDirectory` method.

```
/**
 * Makes REST API request and writes the file to the location provided.
 * @param {object} options : Request option to make REST API request.
 * @param {string} fileOutputPath : Downloaded file's absolute path.
 */
const writeTheFileIntoDirectory = (options, fileOutputPath) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        // Get file downloaded.
        const stream = fs.createWriteStream(fileOutputPath);
        return request
            .get(options.url, options, (err, res, body) => {
                if (res.statusCode < 200 || res.statusCode >= 400) {
                    const bodyObj = JSON.parse(body);
                    const error = bodyObj.error;
                    error.statusCode = res.statusCode;
                    return reject(error);
                }
            })
            .on('error', error => reject(error))
            .pipe(stream)
            .on('close', () => resolve(fileOutputPath));
    });
}
```

The beauty of nodejs is that it support backward compatibility of different asynchronous implementation. If a method is returning promise, then `await` will be kicked in and will wait for the method to be completed.

Above `writeTheFileIntoDirectory` method will download the file and will return positively when the stream is closed successfully, else it will return error.