# CRC32 checksum is not getting calculated in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, crc32, busboy

I'm writing a `node.js` server where I accept a file along with a CRC32 checksum in a multipart request. I am using `busboy` and `crc` node modules to handle multipart requests and CRC operations in node.

In the `busboy`'s `finish` event, I am attempting to calculate the CRC32 checksum of the saved file and validating it against the received checksum.

My problem is that in the `finish` event, the checksum is always calculated as 0. If I manually run the CRC32 checksum against the same file, the checksum gets calculated properly.

Here's the code snippet I use to handle the multipart request with crc32 calculation:

```
var busboy = new Busboy({ headers : request.headers});
var saveTo;
var crc32;
busboy.on('file', function (fieldname, file, filename, encoding, mimetype) {
    saveTo = path.join('files', '/', filename);
    file.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(saveTo));
});

busboy.on('field', function(fieldname, val, fieldnameTruncated, valTruncated) {
    if(fieldname == 'checksum') {
        crc32 = val;
    }
});

busboy.on('finish', function() {
    var savedFileCrc32 = crc.crc32(fs.readFileSync(saveTo)).toString(16);
    console.log("CRC32 of saved file: " + savedFileCrc32 + " file: " + saveTo);
});
request.pipe(busboy);
```

My console always prints `CRC32 of saved file: 0 file: files/image.jpg`

However, if I run  a node program to calculate the CRC32 checksum of the file that was just created, it works perfectly and prints the checksum.

The image is also getting saved properly. In the `finish` event, if I open a read stream on`saveTo` and read out the bytes, the image is getting read, so the file already exists.

Any idea what the problem could be?

Comment: if busboy passes the write to the fs stream, does it know when it's done writing?

Comment: I am not sure. I think @tgo has the right thing. I'm going to try writing the file synchronously and checking if that fixes the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing I can think of is that the write is not finished by the time you do the `readFileSync()`. Can you check if the file exists before reading ?

I am also wondering if it's not in fact a [duplicate of this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12906694/fs-createwritestream-does-not-immediately-create-file).

Comment: Hmm.. Good point. Let me try writing the file synchronously and seeing if that makes a different

Comment: That was precisely what was happening. I used multiparty instead to parse the Multipart request, which saves the files to the temp directly and only then gives me the final callback. Thanks!