# Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory - fs.createReadStream that is piped into a fs.createWriteStream

Tags: node.js, file, fs

Below is my code where I am trying to use fs.createReadStream that is piped into a fs.createWriteStream. Its working for one hit. But if I run the same code using concurrent hits getting error as

> Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory

```
var fileReadStream = fs.createReadStream("test.png", {encoding: "utf16le"});
var fileWriteStream = fs.createWriteStream("test1.png", {encoding: "utf16le"});
fileReadStream.pipe(fileWriteStream);
fileReadStream.on('end', function () {
});
fileWriteStream.on('close', function () {
    fileReadStream.on('finish', function () {
        fs.unlink(test1.png);
    })

})
```

I am not that good in filesystem api's. Can someone help me what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: Please look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12906694/fs-createwritestream-does-not-immediately-create-file

Comment: also be sure that your paths are correct, if you are missing a folder you will get this error.

Comment: I am encountering the same problem.  I've narrowed it down to `fs.createWriteStream(path)` as the cause.  `path` is correct, and the file and its parent folders all exist.  After some seconds, the write stream emits an `ENOENT` error.  This is extra confusing because this has worked elsewhere in the code.

Answer (score 3):

Add __dirname + '/test.png' that fixed my error

```
 var fileReadStream = fs.createReadStream(__dirname + <path to image From current directory>, {encoding: "utf16le"});
var fileWriteStream = fs.createWriteStream(__dirname + <path to image From current directory>, {encoding: "utf16le"});
```

Comment: Whenever you answer, try to be as clear about it as possible.