# Save file to disk and then download in Node

Tags: node.js, file, express, axios

I'm downloading a file from remote server using axios post method,then saving to the disk.
Once the file is saved to disk I need to send it to client in response.

```
let response = await axios.post(url, body, {headers :headers, responseType:'stream'})
let filePath = "reports/" + response.headers['content-disposition'].split("filename=")[1].replace(/\"/g, "");
await response.data.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(filePath)) 
res.download(filePath);
```

The problem I'm facing is, Response is sent when the file writing is still in progress.
If there is any alternative, Please suggest.

EDIT:-
The problem was with the write stream.

Solution:-

```
let response = await axios.post(url, body, {headers :headers, responseType:'stream'});
let filePath = "reports/" + response.headers['content-disposition'].split("filename=")[1].replace(/\"/g, "");
let ws = fs.createWriteStream(filePath);
new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
ws.on('open', () => {
    response.data.pipe(ws);
}).on('error', function (err) {
    reject(res.send({error: "message"}));
}).on('finish', function () {
   ws.end();
   resolve(res.download(filePath));
 });
});
```

Link:- [fs.createWriteStream does not immediately create file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12906694/fs-createwritestream-does-not-immediately-create-file)

Comment: When you say response is sent when the file is writing you mean a timeout event is sent?, if so you either need to increase your server timeout (this obv dosen't scale to infinity as files can be enormous) or you'll have to use a `socket` connection instead.

Comment: No, response is sent with file of 0 kb. It's working if I add add delay of 1 sec before sending the response.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should use Promise.All to resolve all promises before moving on.

Answer (score 0):

As much as i know response.data.pipe is not a promise so await is not going to work on it.
Try :-

```
response.data.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(filePath), {end: false})
response.data.on('end', ()=> res.download(filePath))
```