Node.js' createWriteStream ensuring the folder exists
I am currently doing something like this:
const createWritable = async (path) => {
  // Create the folder recursively when it doesn't exist
  await fsp.mkdir(dirname(path), { recursive: true });
  // Create the Node.js writeStream for usage
  return fs.createWriteStream(path);
};

However the problem with this IMHO is that you need to const writable = await createWritable(path) to get the writable. This being a stream and from my attempts, I'm convinced you can somehow combine the async operation into a stream as well. This is the code I've gotten so far, and while "it works" it's also very flaky and re-running it in tests me the classic ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '...' some times:
const createWritable = async (path) => {
  let writer;
  return new Writable({
    async construct(next) {
      await fsp.mkdir(dirname(path), { recursive: true });
      writer = createWriteStream(path);
      next();
    },
    write(chunk, encoding, next) {
      writer.encoding = encoding;
      writer.write(chunk);
      next();
    },
  });
}

So some questions:

Do I need the writer.encoding = encoding? It didn't seem to make a difference for the tests I made, but not sure if it might in some cases or not.
I am probably missing some error handling, right? Is that why the tests are flaky and I'm getting sometimes the ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '...'? It seems more like a timing issue though...
Is there a better way of doing this? I would think if I could combine two streams like Readable(async() => {}).pipe(createWriteStream(path)) or similar that'd be amazing instead of having to do this manually. I couldn't find much info about these details though.


1. Do you need writer.encoding = encoding?
No, you don't need to set writer.encoding = encoding. The encoding passed to the write method is already handled by the underlying stream's write method. Setting it manually isn't necessary and might even cause unexpected behavior if the encoding is set incorrectly.
2. Are you missing error handling?
Yes, the current implementation lacks proper error handling, which could be contributing to the flakiness of your tests. Specifically:

mkdir Errors: If the fsp.mkdir operation fails, it will throw an error if there is an issue making the directory.

createWriteStream Errors: The createWriteStream itself might throw an error if there's an issue with creating or opening the file.


3. Is there a better way to do this?
Yes, there's a more reliable way to handle this using Node.js's built-in pipeline or handling streams more gracefully with async operations. Here’s an alternative approach:
const { pipeline, Writable } = require('stream');
const { promisify } = require('util');
const fsp = require('fs').promises;
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

// Convert pipeline to a promise-based function
const pipelinePromise = promisify(pipeline);

const createWritable = (filePath) => {
  let writer;
  return new Writable({
    async construct(callback) {
      try {
        // Ensure the directory exists
        await fsp.mkdir(path.dirname(filePath), { recursive: true });
        // Create the write stream
        writer = fs.createWriteStream(filePath);
        callback();
      } catch (err) {
        callback(err);
      }
    },
    write(chunk, encoding, callback) {
      if (!writer.write(chunk, encoding)) {
        writer.once('drain', callback);
      } else {
        callback();
      }
    },
    final(callback) {
      writer.end(callback);
    }
  });
};

// Example usage
async function example() {
  const writable = createWritable('/some/path/to/file.txt');

  // You can now use `pipeline` with a readable stream
  await pipelinePromise(
    someReadableStream,
    writable
  );
}


Thanks a lot! It seems my ENOENT bug was fixed by just adding await new Promise((done) => writer.on("open", done)); in the constructor (source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12906805/938236) but this was def helpful! I've switched to WebStream in the end (then Writable.fromWeb()), but if you add that writer.on("open") bit I'll accept this since it gave many improvements!
